# How do I derive this equation for total energy of an oscillating spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, harmonic-oscillator, spring

My textbook reads:

> *One more thing: there’s a nice formula for the energy stored in an oscillating spring.  It is proportional to the square of the amplitude and the square of the frequency:*
>   $$E  =2\pi^2\nu^2A^2M.$$

How did they derive this equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The energy of a static displaced (by $A$) string is computed from the work done to get it there:

$$ E = \int_0^A{F(x)dx} = \int_0^A{kxdx}=\frac 1 2 k A^2 $$

Meanwhile, if you solve the equation of motion for a spring:

$$ m\ddot x(t)+kx(t)=0$$

you get a single frequency:

$$2\pi\nu = \sqrt{\frac k M} $$

so that:

$$ k = (2\pi)^2\nu^2M$$

Plug that into the expression for E.

Answer (score 2):

One of the advantages of showing that the motion is simple harmonic is that you can use a series of relationships which relate to the motion.
In this case of answering this question you can say that the total energy stored in the spring-mass system is equal to the maximum kinetic energy of the system.
Maximum kinetic energy occurs when the speed is a maximum $= 2\pi \nu A$ where $\nu$ is the frequency of the motion and $A$ the amplitude.
So the maximum kinetic energy is $\frac 12 M (2\pi \nu A)^2 = 2 \pi^2 \nu^2A^2 M$ and this is equal to the total energy stored in the spring-mass system.